# how to get the probability $p=1−(1−1/N)^{Tma_i}$ of extracting at least one ball in the urn

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, polya-urn-model

I am reading [supplementary information](http://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/srep/2012/120625/srep00469/extref/srep00469-s1.pdf) of the paper [Activity driven modeling of dynamic networks](http://www.nature.com/articles/srep00469). It analogys the number of out degree of a activity node by Polya urns problem:

> it will equal to  the number of different balls extracted from a urn
>   with $N$ balls, performing $Tma_i$ extractions. The probability of
>   extracting $d$ balls will be given by
>
> $$P(d)= \begin{pmatrix} N \\ d \end{pmatrix} p^d(1-p)^{(N-d)}$$
>
> where
>
> $$p=1-(1-\frac{1}{N})^{Tma_i}$$
>
> is the probability of extracting at least one ball in the urn.

I just even dont know why to treated this as Binormial Distribution? How to get `the probability of extracting at least one ball in the urn`? What's the solving detail? Thanks for your consideration. Am I clear about my question? Do you need more information for answering my question?

It should looks like:

[image]

If there are more than one edges between two nodes, only one edge should be chosen. *e6* *e1* *e8* treated as same ball. For the figure above there should be 9 balls in a urn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an account of what that maths *does* model.

Consider an urn with $M$ balls and one golden ball. Consider $E:= Tma_i$ selections, $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_E$ from the urn *with replacement*. $\mathbb{P}[X_i=\text{gold}]=\frac{1}{N}$ and the $X_i$ are pairwise independent.

What is the probability that the golden ball is selected at some point?

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\text{not selected}]&=\mathbb{P}[(X_1\neq \text{gold})\cap(X_2\neq\text{gold})\cap\cdots\cap(X_E\neq\text{gold})]
\\&\prod_{i=1}^E\mathbb{P}[X_i\neq\text{gold}]
\\&=\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^E
\\\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}[\text{selected}]&=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^E:=p.
\end{align}$$

Now consider $N$ urns, each with $M$ balls, and each with a golden ball (suppose in addition the golden ball in urn $i$ has a little stamp "$i$" on it).

Now if we are going to make $E$ selections from the $N$ urns, then the probability that we select the golden ball at least once is $p$ in each case. Furthermore these probabilities are independent. Therefore if $Y$ is the number of urns for which the $E$ selections yields a golden ball, $Y\sim \operatorname{Bin}[N,p]$ and so
$$\mathbb{P}[Y=d]={N\choose d}p^d(1-p)^{N-d}.$$

Comment: When you said N urns, do you mean do the experiment N times in a urn, since it is *replacement*?

Comment: No I mean N different but identical urns. Alternatively yes the question can be selecting E balls and stop. Have you got the golden ball at least once. Plus one for yes, zero for no. Repeat N-1 more times keeping a running total. The probability given equals the probability that in d of the N trails, the golden ball was seen at least once

Comment: The number of balls in the urn is M and different from N.

Comment: I am a little confused about the golden ball now. Does it the ball which must be selected?

Comment: Yes: Let $Y_i=1$ if the golden ball is seen at least once in the $E$ selections of urn $i$ and $Y_i=0$ if the golden ball is not seen once during the $E$ selections of urn $i$. $Y=Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_N$. This is with $N$ urns.

Comment: Alternatively, consider $N$ lots of $E$ selections, say $S_1,\dots,S_N$. Let $Y_i=1$ if the golden ball is seen at least once during $S_i$ and $Y_i=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Then, what is difference between **selected** and **golden ball**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39234/discussion-between-nick-dong-and-jp-mccarthy).